# How to use Index on SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am new in this. I am using MySql Workbench. `I want to use index on select clause.` so the performance will be increased. see my query which i have tried.

```
SELECT entity_row_id
FROM entity_association USE INDEX(entity_row_id)
WHERE assoc_entity_row_id IN ('1123')
  AND (deleted =0
       OR deleted IS NULL)
```

I am getting this error. But that column exist in the entity_association Table.

`Error: 1176. Key 'entity_row_id' doesn't exist in table 'entity_association'`

Please suggest me if is their any change in my query.

Comment: what does the following shows ? `show indexes from entity_association`

Comment: You can only use index that is already created. So in order to use index on a particular field, first create one and then use it.

Comment: could you please show me an example. so that i will get idea.

Comment: Can you post the table structure. For creating index you can look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

## How to use Index on SQL Query?

`Firstly`, do you mean you're creating the index in a stored procedure? That's a bad idea - if you run the stored procedure twice, it will fail because the index already exists.

`Secondly`, your query doesn't use the column mentioned in the index, so it will have no impact.

`Thirdly`, as JodyT writes, the query analyzer (SQL Server itself) will decide which index to use; it's almost certainly better at it than you are.

`Finally`, to speed up the query you mention, create an index on columns artc and atelr.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have index in sql query. We only have it on database structure.

Please use

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD INDEX `entity_row_id` (`entity_row_id`)
```

Comment: Thanks hoangvu68 i will try this one .. :)

Comment: If you have phpmyadmin in your computer, I think very easy to do it. Don't need use script, we can do it by using inteface.